# Wordpress: Changing the wp-content Temp Directory to /tmp

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make WordPress use a temporary directory for wp-content, possibly a /tmp directory, i assume that once upgrade or plugin installation finishes WordPress would replace actual wp-contents in the root folder that is /var/www/html/wp-contents, i used the below setting in wp-config.php.

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp');
```

but once i try to upgrade it checks the */var/www/html/tmp/* directory, says

```
Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
```

i need to use /tmp not /var/www/html/tmp

Will give neccesary permissions and owenership to /tmp

Edit: There's an Automated upgrade issue with WordPress on AWS EFS storage, so using settings WP_CONTENT_DIR or WP_UPGRADE_DIR isn't working for me.

Comment: first give right permissions to `/tmp` directory, then check it again. It's look like, your `define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmp');` is working

Comment: That means that it looks for /tmp folder without permissions and falls back to that /var/www/html/tmp/ location ?

Comment: rught. look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir and here. give right permission and try again

Comment: I tried that, no luck, still it looks for the /var/www/html/tmp/  directory.

Comment: where is locating your wordpress installation, and where is locating `tmp` folder?

Comment: tmp is actually a linux temporary directory located at ' / ' that we can find along side /etc, /var, /usr etc, wordpress installation is at /var/www/html.

The reason i'm doing this is because /var/www/html is mounted on AWS EFS, for some reason automatic update is stuck, but manual update works but i need it automatically, /tmp is on docker container.

Comment: I see. you want to do it because of some autoupload issues. try this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165195/133553 and dont forget to create folder `wp-content/temp` before adding `constant`

Comment: Yes, so its should be /tmp/wp-content/temp ? I did mentioned that but its looking at /var/www/html/tmp/wp-content/temp folder.

Comment: not `/tmp/wp-content/temp`, but `/var/www/html/{your-website-folder}/wp-content/tmp`. I think there isn;t difference for you, where the folder will be. Your main goal is to make work. But when your trying to use server `tmp` folder, it may occure both security and permissions issues